# Ubuntu and Win10 on separate discs - where to put the Ubuntu Boot Loader

Tags: partition, boot-loader

I have an SSD with Win10 and a new NVMe SSD that I want to use for Ubuntu. Therefore, I did the Ubuntu expert installation and created three partitions: the primary one for Ubuntu, a logical partition that I want to use for DropBox, OwnCloud and other shared data, and finally a swap partition. Then the installer asked for the install target for the boot loader. Here I selected `/dev/nvme1` (the new disk, but no specific partition).

**Problem**: After the installation the layout of the disks looks somewhat like this:

```
/dev/nvme1 (Ubuntu)
-------------------------------------------------------------
|     extJournaled        |   FAT32              |   SWAP   |
|     (Ubuntu)            |   (shared storage)   |          |
|     /dev/nvme1p1        |   /dev/nvme1p2       |          |
|     mount: /            |   mount: /cloud      |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------

/dev/ssd1 (Windows)
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  Win Boot     |  /boot/EFI    |  NTFS                     |
|  Loader       |               |  (Windows 10)             |
|  /dev/ssd1p1  |  /dev/ssd1p2  |  /dev/ssd1p3              |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can not find the Ubuntu boot loader there. Within the BIOS of the main board neither Ubuntu boot loader nor the NVM SSD are available as boot options. But if I start with the main board's (MSI M350b Mortar Arctic) boot menu (F11) then I see Windows and the Ubuntu boot loader where the Ubuntu boot loader is shown to be on /dev/ssd1 and not on the NVM SSD. I can manually select Ubuntu here. This brings up the Ubuntu boot loader where I then need to start Ubuntu.

So my problems are a) I don't see the the Ubuntu boot loader in the partition layout and b) I cannot add Ubuntu to the Windows boot loader and c) I cannot select Ubuntu in the boot order of the BIOS.

**What I'd like to have** is just one boot loader coming up asking me to either start Windows or Ubuntu or using the F11 key of the BIOS and then start either Windows or Ubuntu without having the boot loader asking me again.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try booting into Ubuntu and then following the instructions [here][How can I fix/install/reinstall grub?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492)). In your case, since the system can be booted, you can skip the first steps and just do steps 4-7, changing `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/nvme1`. Let me know if that works and I'll mark as a duplicate.

Comment: Would this remove the boot loader from the SDD as well?

Comment: Didn`t work. Same situation as before. I can access the Ubuntu Bootloader via the F11 key of the main board. But cant see it in the BIOS boot ordering. If I dont press any key, Windows will start by default.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see the the Ubuntu boot loader in the partition layout

You have an EFI system, which means that more likely than not the Ubuntu installer put the Linux kernel EFI stub, and perhaps other files, into your EFI partition which is `/dev/ssd1p2`. Hence, there's no need to install GRUB to `/dev/nvme`. Check the contents of `/boot/EFI`.

> I cannot add Ubuntu to the Windows boot loader

There's no need to do this. What you need is a *boot manager* to allow you to select which of the *EFI stubs* to boot. For this you can use [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). If I'm not mistaking, you can install rEFInd from Ubuntu.

> I cannot select Ubuntu in the boot order of the BIOS.

Once you have rEFInd installed this won't matter because it will act as your boot menu; detecting which EFI stubs you have installed (Windows and Ubuntu) and presenting a menu to boot them. The only caveat is that sometimes an OS update will change the default boot manager to something else. In that case, you'll just need to change it back to rEFInd. The [installation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) instructions cover this process.

### Example EFI partition

```
/boot
/boot/EFI
/boot/EFI/APPLE
/boot/EFI/APPLE/EXTENSIONS
/boot/EFI/APPLE/EXTENSIONS/Firmware.scap
/boot/EFI/APPLE/FIRMWARE
/boot/EFI/APPLE/FIRMWARE/MM61_0106_B0B_LOCKED.scap
/boot/EFI/systemd
/boot/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
/boot/EFI/BOOT
/boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
/boot/EFI/nixos
/boot/EFI/nixos/cvh39057xaz7wlxyllc2xsshfjz1cw1y-linux-4.9.53-bzImage.efi
/boot/EFI/nixos/8fyh1aijvkrzrsmkxifvjmvhkh9zhnr1-initrd-initrd.efi
/boot/EFI/nixos/xjlwbp1gf874jvyhqn7fkvi8mbsyaspa-linux-4.9.56-bzImage.efi
/boot/EFI/nixos/m01j5hf4hxqj0bg83k2ph0s8rarlpp5d-initrd-initrd.efi
/boot/loader
/boot/loader/entries
/boot/loader/entries/nixos-generation-79.conf
/boot/loader/entries/nixos-generation-80.conf
/boot/loader/loader.conf
```

Comment: This would override the Windows Bootmanager? Or not - since the EFI is another partition?

Comment: Yes, but not at the filesystem level, but rather an EFI setting. The Windows bootmanager would still exist but it won't be launched as the default. But since it's such a critical component it's working making a backup of the EFI partition first.

Comment: how to check the contents of /boot/efi? anyway, not sure if I wanna install a new boot manager to EFI

Comment: PS: tried installing rEFInd and installation worked. but still no different boot behaviour

Comment: The `efibootmgr` step may not have worked; the step which sets the boot manager. Consider posting the output of `efibootmgr` As for listing the contents of `/boot/efi`, use your work-around to boot Ubuntu and then run `export MNTDIR=$(mktemp -d) && mount -o ro /dev/ssd1p2 $MNTDIR && find $MNTDIR && umount $MNTDIR`

Comment: Common, I am a newbie and can not go so much into detail. Anyway, I reinstalled Ubuntu and create a smaller shirt partition for EFI on the NVMe SSD and set the boot loader to be located there. Works. But still I have to use F11 to get the main board boot menu and then start ubuntu loader. I also found an option in the Bios to set Ubuntu first. But now I got for MBR entries, Windows, the old Ubuntu, the new Ubuntu and that reEFInd. I managed to delete the old entries from the Windows EFI, but still they are shown up. bootrec /fixmbr doesnt work either.

Comment: `bootrec /fixmbr` didn't work because you have an EFI, not MBR system. On an EFI system the idea setup is to have a single EFI partition, rather than two. Otherwise you'll have to keep selecting which boot manager you want (F11 key). I added an example EFI partition of my Mac Mini with Mac OS and NixOS. The file `/boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` is the default boot manager which came with the system. `/boot/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi` was installed by NixOS and is now my default boot manager. The default boot manager can be set with `efibootmgr`: https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr

Comment: Admittedly, `efibootmgr` is not intuitive. But it's best to stay the course and slowly work the problem so you don't end up with a mess.